# network communication using python and socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have succesfully made a code which starts a server which can be connected by other devices on my LAN with the CMD command `telnet hostname port` when the new "client" enters a word and presses enter the word is then sent back to them through the server. My question is if i connected 2 devices to the server how would i get the message to get sent from one to the server then back to the other. Like a messaging programme. The code i have used is shown below

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print('Waiting for a connection.')

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))
    final_char = ""

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        char = data.decode("utf-8")
        print(data)
        if data != b'\r\n':
            final_char += char
            print(final_char)
        else:


            reply = 'Server output: '+ final_char+"\n"
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            final_char = ""
    conn.close()



while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(addr)
    print(conn)
    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual implementation, but some theory:

You need to keep a list of all the clients you have an active connection to:

```
while ( true )

    client = server.accept()

    clientList.add(client)

    startThread(client)
```

Then in the thread

```
while ( true )

    data = connection.receive()

    for client in clientList

        client.sendall( data )
```

Comment: how do i create a list? which i can add other clients to. would an array work?

Comment: Yep, an array should work. I didn't give an actual impl as Python is not my forte.

Comment: @J.Fitz It will not work! You are passing `client` to different threads in your pseudo-code.

Comment: it's cool. The only reason i am struggling as server.accept() returns 2 values the ip/port as the first value and the socket as the second e.g. `<socket.socket fd=728, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('host', port), raddr=('client ip', client port)>`

Comment: @J.Fitz you really only need to keep a list of the socket, I think you can get the address from the socket at a later time if you still need it. Or add the addresses to their own list? The theory here is that you need to keep track of all the sockets, which are the streams to the client. You do not have to track the address.

Comment: @MattClark OP is using threads! `for client in clientList` will run in every thread. It is blocking and a socket can not be used by multiple threads/routines/processes in a given time.

Comment: ( again, not actual code, just theory, the actual impl should look very very different ) Wait, in python you can not hold a reference to the same socket and use it in two different threads? I do plenty of socket work in Java, I have no idea how python fakes it multi-threadedness, so I guess I can not comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ZQM the python library works perfect and it has already implemented what you need using sockets internally.
https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Take a look at their publisher / subscriber message pattern.

Comment: I have looked at this site and at the publisher / subscriber section but i can't seem to get my head around it. could you explain more further?

Comment: Take a look at the example. It's straightforward.
https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html